# Select "selected element" again from select box angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

Let's say I have the following basic select box html.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="showSelected()">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

And following controller:

```
$scope.showSelected = function () {
        console.log('Selected');
        //TODO
    }
```

Here, lets say I select 'option-1' first, and then there will be console log.
Now I want to select same element again and trigger the function again. However, showSelected() function will not be triggered, because I havent changed the model, it is again 'option-1'.

"ng-click" directive also not working in select box. So I cannot trigger the function by ng-click.

What is the angular way solution for this particular problem?

Comment: *And also I dont want to use $watcher

Comment: Why do you want to trigger it again ? As the action is already taken by initial `ng-change` handler..

Comment: Hi @haldun - just a quick note - you can edit your original post if you want to make changes/additions by clicking on the [`edit` link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36332470/edit) just underneath the tag list.

Comment: Did you try another event handler, maybe ng-click is what you re looking for.

Comment: Can you use ng-blur to your element

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1752/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
selected val={{}}
 <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-mouseup="showSelected()">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>



function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.open=false;
    $scope.showSelected = function () {
    if($scope.open) {
    // here s your code for select
        console.log('Selected');
    }
    $scope.open=!$scope.open;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the valid answer. What about the "touch" event instead of "mouseup" ? I will use it on tablet.

Comment: I checked it on windows simulator with touch event, it is working

Comment: Hi Naeem, your answer is erroneous. Instead of selecting element from select box, if you cancel the selecting action, you cannot open select box again.

Comment: In order to produce it, click select box, and then instead of selecting "option-1" or "option-2", click somewhere else in the page to cancel the action. Then dropdown will be canceled and closed. And then try to open selectbox again, it will not open.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to trigger once again the event ? If you have to do so, just reset your selectbox, then the event will be triggered again.

Comment: It is not a valid response. I want to use it like a button, think that I want to click the selected element again to trigger same function without changing the selected element.

Comment: Ok, maybe try to think in a different way : do not use html native element select but simulate it in html/css with a ul containing <a> elements with wich you can use ng-click events !